# Is the Set of Continuous Functions that are the Sum of Even and Odd Functions Meager?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

> Consider $X = \mathcal{C}([−1,1])$ with the usual norm $\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{t\in [−1,1]}|f(t)|.$
>
> Define
>   $$\mathcal{A}_{+}=\{ f \in X : f(t)=f(−t) \space \forall t\in [−1,1]\},$$
>   $$\mathcal{A}_{−}=\{ f \in X : f(t)=−f(−t) \space \forall t \in [−1,1]\}. $$
>
> Is $\mathcal{A}_{+} +\mathcal{A}_{−} = \{f +g : f \in \mathcal{A}_{+},g \in \mathcal{A}_{−}\}$ meager?
>
> ---

I know this set is dense by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. However, that doesn't really help. I also know that if the set is closed, then it is meager, but I have difficulties deciding whether it is closed or not. I know the exponential function is a limit of a sequence of a sum of even and odd functions, however one could define it to be that, in which case it doesn't help.

---

Any hints on how to get going on this problem, and on whether the set $\mathcal{A}_{+}+{A}_{-} $ is closed or not? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that any function can be written as
$f(x) = {1 \over 2} (f(x) + f(-x)) + {1 \over 2} (f(x) - f(-x)) $, so
$\mathcal{A}_{+} +\mathcal{A}_{−} = X$, which is not meagre.

(It is not meagre because $C[-1,1]$ is a complete metric space.)

Comment: As an aside, if OP is familiar with Fourier series this decomposition should be part of the associated intuition.

Comment: @R.. Fourier decomposition is _way_ more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Absolutely. copper.hat's answer is simpler and more direct, but having studied Fourier series should leave one with an intuition that there is a natural decomposition into even and odd parts, whereas otherwise this may seem like a surprising and/or obscure result.

Comment: @R.. hm, I rather see it the other way around – this decomposition is one of the foundations that make Fourier analysis possible. But, I suppose this is somewhat a matter of taste.

Comment: I guess I would see the decomposition of square matrices into symmetric and skew symmetric parts a more natural intuition. Fourier series requires a lot more baggage.